# TSX files will not automatically show errors in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

I am building a Next.js app using typescript. My main problem is that .tsx files will not show me if there are errors in those files (not runtime errors, normal syntax errors) before I open them. I always have to open each file in my project or wait for my project to break and for it to tell me that there is a syntax error somewhere.

Also, errors are loading really really slow. Whenever I do a syntax error, or I solve one, it will take like 5 seconds for the file to update and the error to either appear or disappear.

Are there any ways of getting better error loading and live syntax errors in TSX files?

Answer (score -2):

Try these suggestions that should be a help to speed up error checking ahead of time, rather than at runtime:

###### 1. IDE with built-in TypeScript support

like VS Code

###### 2. TypeScript linter

like ESLint: see [TypeScript Web Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Noctarya.typescript-web-development-extension-pack)

**Then try following tweaks:**

###### 1. Disable unnecessary extensions:

Extensions can sometimes impact performance. Disable any extensions that you don't need or suspect might be causing the slowdown. You can disable extensions by going to the Extensions view in VS Code and clicking on the gear icon next to the extension you want to disable, then selecting "Disable".

###### 2. Adjust IntelliSense settings:

IntelliSense, which provides code suggestions and error checking, can also affect performance. You can try adjusting the IntelliSense settings to see if it improves the error loading speed. Open the VS Code settings (`File > Preferences > Settings` or by pressing `Ctrl+,`), search for "IntelliSense" and experiment with different settings like `editor.quickSuggestions`, `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters`, and `editor.suggestDelay`.

I hope these suggestions help you to improve the error loading speed in VS Code.